# Поиск суммы элементов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие примерно такое.
"Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка."
C кодом помогли.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for elem in range(len(a)):
    if len(a) == 1:
        print(a[0])
    else:
        print(a[elem - 1] + a[(elem + 1) % len(a)], end=' ')
```

Он рабочий. Только его не объяснили совсем. Может ли кто-то объяснить для "чайников" пошагово? Сам не понимаю. Теряется весь смысл(( Спасибо

Comment: А что, если почитать о самых основах языка Python? Многое прояснится. Какая именно строка непонятна?

Comment: print(a[elem - 1] + a[(elem + 1) % len(a)], end=' ') elem - это значение элемента, его индекс?

Comment: индекс, поскольку цикл задан  в пределах длины массива `in range(len(a)):`

Comment: Теперь все стало на свои места a[-1]  - это последний элемент списка. Спасибо огромное

Comment: Кроме того, a[]  - доступ к элементы списка по индексу

Comment: Я новичок совсем в питоне. Меня путает то, что длинна списка начинается с 1. а индексы с 0.